# EXCEL: How do I count a pattern of values across multiple cells?

Tags: excel, count, cell, formula

I have an attendance spreadsheet with values "OFF", "VAC", "HOL" and "SCK".  I am trying to identify abuse of the SICK day policy where employees use their SICK days to extend their weekends, vacation or holidays.  I would like to count the number of time these two text values are *within four cells* of each other in the same row a large range.

[image]

In this example, the count would yield an answer of "3" because there are 3 occurrences where the employee was SICK immediately before or after an "OFF" day.

Is this possible in a formula?

Comment: http://search.dilbert.com/comic/40%25%20Sick

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your picture how many cells are involved, is "SCK" on 24th 4 cells after "OFF" on 23rd?

If so try using a `COUNTIFS` function with the ranges offset by 4 cells, e.g.

`=COUNTIFS(A1:Z100,"OFF",E1:AD100,"*SCK")`

adjust ranges as required